# AutoFit all active rows / columns in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, worksheet

I want to create a macro autofit all rows and columns with values in them in across all worksheets in a workbook. This is what I have so far, I am stuck. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub AutoFitColumnsRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
     Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Next

starting_ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit` refers cells in the active sheet. You need to fully qualify the range to be autofit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you need the other variables you have defined, but the basic loop looks like this:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Next
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help. With that, I am getting a debug error- "Method AutoFit of object range failed" Any idea why?

Comment: Are any of the sheet protected?

Comment: No they're not protected

Comment: Not sure then, as it works just fine for me. I guess first figure out which sheet it's erroring on, and then look for something that makes that sheet unusual. Have you tried it in a simpler workbook?

Comment: I created a new workbook and just copied everything over and it worked! Thanks for the help